# Work done by a person climbing stairs, who or what does the work?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work

I've seen other questions like this but didn't really see any answers.

When a person climbs stairs, the object is the person. Yet we say the person did work...how so? Doesn't work mean an external force had to be applied over a distance to make an object have a change in KE or PE?

Isn't the work more less from the muscles of the person. The stairs didn't do work. Then really isn't the work internal work done, where the work done is causing and changing their chemical energy to kinetic?

I get work done on a box or more complex systems. But who or what does the work in climbing stairs if it is the person themselves in the system. Why don't physics books explain these type of examples. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to estimate the work done by a climber?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/306516/what-is-the-correct-way-to-estimate-the-work-done-by-a-climber), related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/511698/170832

Comment: Disagree that the linked duplicate is appropriate.  This question is asking where the work is being done.  The marked duplicate does not raise or address that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A person is not a rigid body (like a box), so you can't do a simple analysis that treats the person's interaction with the stairs that way.

Better would be to model the person as a mass on top of a piston (or pair of pistons).

As the person climbs, the leg muscles (piston) push the body upward.  The piston is pushing on the moving body, so work is being done.  After the body is raised, the piston is moved to a higher step so the work can be repeated.

The piston also pushes on the stairs, but since the stairs don't move, no work is being exchanged with them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea.  The situation is equivalent to an engine that delivers power to a car to make it go up a hill.  In that situation, we say the work is done by the engine.  The muscles in a person perform the same function as the engine of a car: they power the body to climb the stairs.  From the work-energy perspective, looking at work as a change in potential energy ($W = -\Delta U$), chemical energy is converted to potential energy (in the $U = mgh$ sense) via the engine or the muscles, so that total energy is conserved but potential energy is not.

Edit: to elaborate on energy conservation perspective, you could model it as chemical energy (muscles activating) converted into kinetic energy (legs start moving) and then to potential energy (person climbs steps). To calculate the work involved, you could treat it as equivalent to a point-mass with an initial upward velocity, decelerating due to gravity until its velocity was zero, which would occur at a distance $h$ . The work would be the force ($−mg$) times the distance ($h$), which is equivalent to the change in potential energy $-\Delta U$. Where would you get the initial velocity? That's the chemical energy converted to kinetic energy.

Comment: I'm ok with this except for the phrase "looking at work as a change in potential energy ()" because it has nothing to do with the answer.  There is no work done, potential energy does not increase because of work, although you do imply that later.  So the phrase can be misleading.

Comment: @garyp Yes, that could use some elaboration, but I didn't include it because I thought it was a detail that would just add confusion.  The OP was asking about work, which is normally defined as $W = \int {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf x}$.  However, that is equal to $-\Delta U$ for a displacement in a conservative field without change to velocity, i.e., when kinetic energy is constant.  That is roughly the situation with someone who has climbed up stairs.

Comment: Okay so work is done by muscles in climbing. Is to wrong to say the work done by the muscles is converting chemcial energy to potential energy? That's what's happening technically right? Our muscles do work, becuase we have energy from food and such, but this work becomes an increase in PE. In most cases we don't worry or think of all that. Just look at it generally as work done on a body/person to climb and use the equation w=fd=mgh

Comment: No, that is not roughly the situation with someone who climbs the stairs.  $W=0$, which implies $\Delta U = 0$.     Here conservation of energy is $0=\Delta K + \Delta U + \Delta E_\mathrm{chemical}$ with, of course, $\Delta K = 0$

Comment: @garyp: That's incorrect.  Work was performed to lift the person from the bottom to the top of the flight of stairs.  That amount of work is equal to $mgh$, where $h$ is the height of the stairs.

Comment: @Kevin: yes, the muscles convert chemical energy to (ultimately) potential energy, which is how energy is conserved.  The work done is just the physical reconfiguration (force $\times$ distance, or $-\Delta U$).  I've edited the response to hopefully make that a bit more clear.

Comment: Richter65, so chemical energy is converted to PE thru work being done by the muscles. We can calculate this as fxd or mgh. Correct? If so, thank you for all the help

Comment: I would use "work" in the technical sense: $\int {\bf F} \cdot d{\bf x}$, meaning something (in this case, the person's body) moving some distance under the influence of some force. So when you say "work done by the muscles", technically there is no work unless there is some movement under some force.  Instead, I'd say the muscles provide the energy (via chemical reactions) which is used to perform the work.

Comment: I get that. The muscles use energy which expand and contract to move bones which is the force thru the distance when talking about work. However, I just was being general on that topic. I just wanted to make sure my understanding was correct as you said. Simply the Body does the work (thru muscles and such)

Comment: Work is energy that enters (or leaves) a system by the application of an external force, and the displacement of the point of application of the force.  If the system is the person, and the force is the normal force of the stairs on his shoes, no work is done.  And other than gravity, there are no other forces.  The work done to climb the stairs is zero.  The situation here is more complex than introductory examples for two reasons:  the system is deformable, and it contains an energy source.  Nonetheless, the work done here is zero.

Comment: @garyp: If the initial state is a person (say, at rest) at the bottom of the stairs, and the final state is the person at rest at the top, then the work required to lift the person is (modulo a sign) $mgh$. You claim the net work must be zero because it's a closed system and therefore there must be an offsetting amount of work associated with the energy source which exactly balances out the work of lifting the person.  But there are two flaws with that reasoning: (1) work is a purely mechanical concept and the energy source is not mechanical, and (2) the system is not closed.  [continued]

Comment: To see this more clearly, ask what would happen if the person went back down the stairs, so that the initial and final states were the same. In that case, $\Delta U = \Delta K = 0$, but by your argument there must be a total amount of work of $2mgh$ performed by the system (one for going up the stairs, another for going down).  And yet, nothing mechanically has changed.  What's really happening is that the muscles are performing an non-adiabatic, irreversible, chemical process to generate energy which is converted to mechanical energy, and the work is a measure of only the mechanical aspect.

Comment: I'm still confused. Why is the physics books say the work done by the muscles/person is mgh? Really as one pushes against the stairs, the stairs reaction force pushes the person up. However, since the point of application is zero, that force does no work. So what force is doing the work? Are the books wrong or just simplifying the problems

Comment: But the force *is* doing work: it's lifting the person up.  If the person started at rest (vertically) at the bottom, and ended up at the top, then at some point the vertical velocity must have changed from zero to some non-zero value.  That change in velocity (aka acceleration) can only be caused by a force, which in this case is the (vector) combination of gravity and the force generated by the person due to muscular activity.  The work is the path integral of this net force  over the path taken by the person, which by energy arguments must be equal to $mgh$.

Comment: Richter65, I think your missing my point. The stairs have no energy to give, hence they do no work. I can stand on the stairs all day and they will not move me. So yes I agree the work is done by the person/muscles, but I'm confused as to how. Only thing I can think of is that the muscles and leg push down on the floor, which does create an equal and opposite force, such then the leg/muscles then push upwards lifting the body. It's this force from the muscles thru the distance that is he work. Is that correct?

Comment: @kevin: yes, that's correct.  As you said, pushing down on the floor to create an equal and opposite force is in every way equivalent to having the muscles push the body upward.  In other words, whether you think of pushing down to create an equal and opposite force, or whether you think of being effectively fixed to the floor and pushing upward, it's the same thing, so it doesn't matter which way you think of it.  In the end, the only thing that really matters is that there exists an upward force (however you want to think of it), generated by the muscles, that moves the person up the stairs.